# console log changes source of music but song continues to play the original set state

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a music player with react and it continues to play the same song even though the source has changed

```
//import react into the bundle
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

//include bootstrap npm library into the bundle
import "bootstrap";

//include your index.scss file into the bundle
import "../styles/index.scss";

const Songs = () => {
  const [music, setMusic] = useState(null);

  const [source, setSource] = useState(
    "https://assets.breatheco.de/apis/sound/files/mario/songs/castle.mp3"
);

useEffect(
    () =>
        fetch("https://assets.breatheco.de/apis/sound/songs")
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => setMusic(data)),
    []
);

return (
    <div className="container text-center">
        <ul>
            {music === null
                ? "Loading..."
                : music.map((t, index) => (
                        <li
                            key={index}
                            id="mysound"
                            className="songs"
                            onClick={() => {
                                setSource(
                                    "https://assets.breatheco.de/apis/sound/" +
                                        t.url
                                );
                                console.log(source);
                            }}>
                            {t.name}
                        </li>
                  ))}
        </ul>
        <audio controls>
            <source src={source} type="audio/mpeg" />
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Songs />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: pass and change some prop (f.e. `index`) in `<audio controls/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the source to your `<audio>` component will re-render it when the source changes.

```
    <audio controls src={source}>
        <source src={source} type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

Working version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dream-5pcni

Comment: Also, your console log will likely show the last state of `source` since `setSource` will update it asynchronously.